# Can a medical provider be paid to display some advertisement for medical services/treatments/products in their office?

Tags: united-states, california, medical, advertisements, payment

Can  a medical provider be paid to display some advertisement for medical services/treatments/products in their office? If so, does the medical provider have to disclose that they had received payments to display such medical advertisements?

I am mostly interested in the following locations in the United States:

- California, United States
- Massachusetts, United States